# IdentityServer4 Force User to re-enter credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 and an MVC client.  When the clients session expires I want my users to be forced to login again.  However no matter what I do IdentityServer seems to automatically log the user back in when the session ends.

My Startup in the client is (session is 30 seconds to test)

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";                                                
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options => { options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30); })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = identityUrl;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.SaveTokens = true;                  
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("Billing");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                options.UseTokenLifetime = false;                   
            });
```

Then my config in IdentityServer is as follows:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "Test",
                ClientName = "Test",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,

                RequireConsent = false,

                IdentityTokenLifetime = 30,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 30,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },              

                RedirectUris = { billingUrl + "/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { billingUrl + "/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "Billing",
                    "role",
                    "VisionBlue.Cloud.BillingAPI"
                },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            },
```

Using fiddler I can see after 30 seconds a request is sent to /connect/authorize on the IdentityServer which is automatically logging the user in again.

Any ideas?   I have set all timeouts to 30 seconds as a test.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the OpenID Connect parameter of `prompt=login` on your authorization request
(https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest). This will tell IdentityServer that you want the user to re-authenticate instead of using SSO or IdentityServer session length.

You should be able to do this in ASP.NET Core using in your OpenIdConnectOptions:

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

There might be an easier way to set this though.

Comment: This is the best answer, as the re-login is needed for example when accesing sensible parts of the system and you want to make sure the user is indeed who he is.

Comment: Thanks!! Saved my life after hours of googling around. In my case i needed user to be logged out and redirected to SSO when accessing part of the system he was not authorized to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct but there is another option and that's the **max_age** param. With that you can specify the max allowed time since **auth_time** and it will automatically prompt the user to authenticate again if this time is exceeded. 
You can also check the **auth_time** claim in the **id_token** when signing it to ensure that it's within your desired window. I'd recommend this as it's easy for end users to remove prompt=login or max_age=xxx from the authorize request should they wish to.

Answer (score 0):

That only expires the cookies on the client application. The IDS cookies must also be set to expire. Look in the `POST` methods for local and external logins.

You'll want to find the section where `AuthenticationProperties` are created (in Quickstart, it's where the `AuthenticationToken` is set), and also set `IsPersistent` and `ExpiresUtc` before the properties are passed to `HttpContext.SignInAsync`.

(Incidentally this can also be used to support persistent login between sessions -- set a long duration in IDS4, then add a non-default OIDC profile to the client and trigger a one-time no-prompt login attempt when a new anonymous session begins.)

Answer (score -1):

If i read right here:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/refresh_tokens.html

This line turns on the automatic re-login:
AllowOfflineAccess = true

set it back to false, this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I still get automatically logged back in with the value set to false.