# Identity Server 4 - Log User Out when Idle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

Hej Community,

I got stuck and I need some advice or pointer to a solution. I have a fairly simple Identity Server 4 Setup:

1. Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET Identity
2. ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC Client

I would like to automatically log out the user after 10 minutes of inactivity. In the sample below I used 10 s to make testing somewhat quicker. The authentication, redirect and user enforced logout work as expected and like a charm using the code below. However, when the user idles for longer than the set 10 s, the user is still signed in and is not redirected to the login page at the IDS host.

The MVC client is setup using Hybrid Grant as:

**Client Definition**

```cs
var mvcClient = new Client
{
    ClientId = "account-mvc",
    ClientName = "Account MVC",
    ClientUri = "https://localhost:5002",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

    EnableLocalLogin = true,
    RequireConsent = false,
    AllowOfflineAccess = false,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 10,   // 10 s by intention
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 10, // 10 s by intention

    RedirectUris = "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc",
    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5002/signout-oidc",

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
    },
};
```

**Identity Server Options**

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Authentication.CheckSessionCookieName = "auth-cookie";
    options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = false;

    options.Csp.Level = IdentityServer4.Models.CspLevel.Two;

    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
})
.Add... // Left out for brevity
```

In the Startup of the MVC client I add:

**MVC Client Startup**

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies", options => 
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.SlidingExpiration = false;
            options.Cookie.Name = "mvc-cookie";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
            options.ClientId = "account-mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
        });
```

and added `app.UseAuthentication()` in the `Configure` method.

**Question**

How can I make sure that the user is signed out at the Identity Server once the session timed out? Any hint and help appreciated!

Comment: Please check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367156/identityserver4-how-to-set-server-cookie-expiration?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After more debugging I found that the cookie lifetime of the MVC client worked as intended with a sliding expiration. However, once the cookie expired, the Idenity Server (IDS) was contacted and the cookie was refreshed as the session was still alive / active at the IDS.

I figured two solutions from which I decided to use *Solution 1* for now and see if it is the most suitable in the long-run.

> If anyone has a comment or recommendation towards security and best practice please comment or post another solution.

#### Solution 1: Maximum SSO lifetime of client

The Client property `UserSsoLifetime` (available in Identity Server 4 from `v2.3`) can be used to set the maximum time until a user must re-authenticate to use the client. So for the sample of the question the only required addition is in the *Client Definition* by adding `UserSsoLifetime = 10`, such as,

**Client Definition**

```cs
var mvcClient = new Client
{
    ClientId = "account-mvc",
    ClientName = "Account MVC",
    ClientUri = "https://localhost:5002",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

    EnableLocalLogin = true,
    RequireConsent = false,
    AllowOfflineAccess = false,
    UserSsoLifetime = 10,       // <- HERE
    AccessTokenLifetime = 10,   // 10 s by intention
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 10, // 10 s by intention

    RedirectUris = "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc",
    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5002/signout-oidc",

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
    },
};
```

This will force the user to re-authenticate after 10 s of inactivity.

#### Solution 2: OIDC Property

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681426/identityserver4-force-user-to-re-enter-credentials) solves the issue with an OIDC property which can be used to force the user to re-authenticate via the login prompt once the session expired - see [@Scotty Brady's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48685072).

So for the example denoted in the question should look like the following. Note that only the MVC client needs changes, namely the Cookie lifetime was removed and OIDC options were added forcing the re-authentication and to use the token lifetime from IDS (each line marked with a `// <- HERE`). This way, the cookie settings from IDS are used (sliding lifetime of 10s).

**MVC Client Startup**

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies") // <- HERE
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
            options.ClientId = "account-mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

            options.UseTokenLifetime = true; // <- HERE
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context => // <- HERE
            {                                                        // <- HERE
                context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";            // <- HERE
                return Task.CompletedTask;                           // <- HERE
            };                                                       // <- HERE

            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
        });
```

Comment: you said available from version 2.3. Does that mean it is available from identity server 2.0?

Comment: I apologize - it might be unclear but it is all related to Identity Server 4, so I mean `v4.2.3`. I edited the answer to avoid confusion. See also [Identity Server 4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html?highlight=UserSsoLifetime#authentication-logout) - last item in the section *Authentication/Logout*.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [End Session Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/endsession.html) of the IdentityServer.

> The end session endpoint can be used to trigger single sign-out ([see spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout)).
>
> To use the end session endpoint a client application will redirect the
>   user’s browser to the end session URL. All applications that the user
>   has logged into via the browser during the user’s session can
>   participate in the sign-out.

You can utilize this endpoint to redirect end user back to login page using **post_logout_redirect_uri** paramter.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I figured how to solve the issue and will document it in a separate answer.