# User to be forced to reenter credentials after 15 minutes

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

i am new to Identity Server (IS4) and authentication/authorization. I am playing around with some scenarios The client app is .netcore 3.1(asp) and the IDP is IS4, version 3.1.3. The one i am trying currently is:

- user tries to go to an area of the client app that requires authentication
- user will enter his credentials against the IDP
- user will be redirected to the client app, and now has access
- user is inactive for 15 minutes
- when user tries to access the same area on the client app, he is required to reenter the credentials

The part I don't manage to make it work is the last one, to force the user to reenter the credentials.I am playing with the options "options.ExpireTimeSpan" (cookie options) and "UseTokenLifetime" (openidconnect options) in the client and "IdentityTokenLifetime" and "AccessTokenLifetime" in the client configuration in the IDP.

Note that although my requirement is for 15 mins, i am trying it with 1 minute in the code snippets below, just for being able to test it quickly.

The settings i have in the client app:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme =CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            })
           .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
           {
               options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.Authority = "https://localhost:46318"; 
               options.ClientId = "Confidential Client Id";
               options.ResponseType = "code";
               options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
               options.UsePkce = true;
               options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
               options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/mycallbackendpoint");
               options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/mycallbackforsignoutendpoint");
               options.Scope.Clear();
               options.Scope.Add("openid");
               options.Scope.Add("profile");
               options.SaveTokens = true;
               options.ClaimActions.MapAll();
               options.ClientSecret = "Confidential Client Secret";
               
           });
```

In IS4 I have a client configured like this:

```
new Client
                {
                     IdentityTokenLifetime = 60,
                     AccessTokenLifetime = 60,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    ClientName = "Confidential Client",
                    ClientId = "Confidential Client Id",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    ClientUri = "http://localhost:47331",
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "http://localhost:47331/mycallbackendpoint"
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "http://localhost:47331/mycallbackforsignoutendpoint"
                    },
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                    },
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("Confidential Client Secret".Sha256())
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: Please note that with SSO the user is signed on automatically as long as the cookie on the IdentityServer is valid. Set [prompt=login](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html?highlight=prompt#authorize-endpoint) to bypass SSO.

Answer (score 1):

I found a SO question where they answer same thing:
[IdentityServer4 Force User to re-enter credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681426/identityserver4-force-user-to-re-enter-credentials)

Although now I realized something, if I don't add the suggested solution for forcing the reentering of the credentials (prompt=login). In my scenario, I don't have the offline access enabled. So I don't understand why I keep getting new tokens with new expiration times (exp)

Comment: when the tokens expire your user is redirected to the identity provider - the identity provider knows who you are through it's cookies and policies so simply issues new tokens. I ran into a similar scenario and I believe the best way to solve this would be in the Identity provider but due to it being out of our jurisdiction we had to settle for a witness mark approach. On sign-in we add a claim for the last authentication time, then in the policy for the resource that requires reauth we check this and force a prompt=login if the login time > X minutes. Not ideal but works for our scenario.